# How to fix CSS of the plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I have installed the same "WP google Translate" plugin on 2 websites. I have noticed that on one of the websites the plugin's pre-set colors and images (flags) are gone (http://prntscr.com/jqdxpx) while on other website all is ok (http://prntscr.com/jqdyc4). I have tried to disable all plugins except this one, but no luck. Also tried to overwrite this plugin from the website where this plugin forks well but no luck. I noticed that any changes to the appearance I make in the settings of this plugin does no effect for it. Any ideas what could cause such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same Theme on both websites? Maybe the theme css is overriding the plugin css?

The best approach to check whats going on, is to use a browser debugger tool.

I use chrome. Hover with your mouse over the problem element, right click and choose 'Inspect'. Chrome dev tools will open and the element is selected. You can then see the Styles (css) that are active for that element.

Do this for both websites and compare the styles that are active.

You will then know the cause of the problem and go on from that point.

p.s. if you need any help you have to share the url's, so i can check for you.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Thaank You @Bjorn I will contact You soon. THANK YOU

Comment: can You please share some contacts like skype or email for further communication please?

Comment: See [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5568708/bjorn?tab=profile) for mail. Don't forget to include both website url's, i'll take a look for you.